# Text input inside a listpicker - Possible?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a WP7 app im working on, I want the user to choose from a list of predefined values in a listpicker (values is loaded from XML, from a website). However I also want them to be able to choose a custom value instead of the predefined ones. 
Is this possible in any way?

I've seen this in Android apps, where a combobox would have a value inside of it called "new value" for example, and when pressed it would launch a pop-up with a textbox to write the new value in.

Do you guys have any idea of how to do this in WP7? Perhaps a sample or article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just add your "new value" item into the source list that your binding the `ListPicker` too, and then check the selected value to see if that item was selected and handle it accordingly?

Comment: This sounds possible, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

For slightly different behaviour you could consider using an [AutoCompleteBox](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291).

As the user starts typing they would be presented with a filtered list of existing options or they could enter their own new option directly, without requiring a separate, additional set of UI elements & associated logic.

Comment: AutoCompleteBox would differ too much from what I want sorry :) Good suggestion though.